# How do I get the whole ListView row when clicking on a item in this row

Tags: android, android-listview, drag

I have a ExpandableListView with four elements in every row. In this row I have a on TouchListener on the first item. Now when I click (and drag) this item I want to drag the whole row and not only the first item and set a background drawable to the whole row.

```
switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                View wholerow = view.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.dbtabellelistviewitem);
                wholerow.setBackgroundDrawable(view.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.circle));

                view.setBackgroundDrawable(view.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.square));
                ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
                view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);


            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                view.setBackgroundDrawable(null);


        }
        return true;
```

But the View wholerow only gives me the first row of the list. How do I get the whole row of the item I clicked?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, I suspect every row created in the view has the same id (defined in the layout). FindViewById stops as soon as it finds a suitable view (with the right id), it doesn't handle views with the same id. That's why your method will always return the first row.

To retrieve the parent row, you need to manually browse through your view's parents with getParent()

A method like this one should work :

```
public View findParentWithId(View myView, int idParent) {
    if (myView.getParent() instanceof View) {
        View parent = (View) myView.getParent();
        if (parent.getId() == idParent) {
            return parent;
        } else {
            return findParentWithId(parent, idParent);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```